# Providing Doxygen with documentation stubs for library classes

Tags: c#, doxygen, inotifypropertychanged

I have a number of classes in my project that implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  I'd like all the PropertyChanged events in each one to be able to inherit the documentation from the interface, but since the interface is not part of my project, it has no Doxygen page.

I'm able to get a partial documentation of the interface with this documentation, the class page appears and the inheritance diagram shows all my classes that implement it. but I'm unable to declare an event.  Is there a keyword I'm missing to add events?

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    /**
     * @class INotifyPropertyChanged
     * @brief Interface to allow subscribers to know when the object has been updated.  See <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx">MSDN Doc</a>
     * @fn void INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged(sender, e)
     * @memberof INotifyPropertyChanged
     * @brief Notification that a property of the object has changed.
     * @details the name of the property is in the event arguments
     * Still having trouble documenting the parameters correctly, but this doesn't inherit anyway because it's a function, not an event
     */
}
```

Or am I totally missing the boat and there's some way to import the Intellisense documentation?

Comment: Are there existing tag files for the .net libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create INotifyPropertyChanged.cs file, put documented interface declaration there, but do not include into any project for compilation, it should be picked only by doxygen.

According to [doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/xmlcmds.html), it supports standard ECMA-334 XML tags, which are normally used to comment C# code, so there is no need to use @class, @brief tags etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that!  I know about the xml style, and it's my preferred style, but you do what the client pays you to do, and the client is asking for @ style docs.

Comment: Getting closer.  The child class Doxygen output lists the event twice in the Events brief summary, once as the child version, once as the interface version.  In the Event Documentation section only the child version is listed. If I add a `/** @copydoc System::ComponentModel::INotifyPropertyChanged::PropertyChanged  */` to the child version, they both get documented.  Without the copydoc, the child version does not get documented.  Making INotifyPropertyChanged a class or interface has the same results.